# Meaning of volatile for arrays and typecasts

Tags: c, arrays, casting, volatile

Folks,

Consider this (abominable) piece of code:

```
volatile unsigned long a[1];  
unsigned long T; 

void main(void) 
{    
    a[0] = 0x6675636b;   /* first access of a */
    T = *a; 
    *(((char *)a) + 3) = 0x64; /* second access of a */
    T = *a;
}
```

...the question: is `((char *)a)` volatile or non-volatile?

This begs a larger question: should there be a dependence between the two accesses of a?  That is, human common sense says there is, but the C99 standard says that volatile things don't alias non-volatile things -- so if `((char *)a)` is non-volatile, then the two accesses don't alias, and there isn't a dependence.

More correctly, C99 6.7.3 (para 5) reads:

> "If an attempt is made to refer to an object defined with a volatile-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-volatile-qualified type, the behavior is undefined."

So when we typecast `a`, does the volatile qualifier apply?

Comment: I think you answered your own question, it is undefined.  In reality I don't think volatile has any effect, it is some kind of compiler hint that is ignored on the common platforms.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling “I don't think volatile has any effect, it is some kind of compiler hint that is ignored on the common platforms” You may be thinking of `register`. The `volatile` type qualifier is very much meaningful in 2012 C code, since the fashions of the moment (for C) are aggressive optimization and embedded applications, both can only cohabitate with programmer hints such as `volatile`.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling, no `volatile` is not only a hint, it is an order to load the value from memory at *every* access.

Comment: @JensGustedt: When you say load the "value from memory".  On x86 in long mode, for example, do you mean the L1 cache, L2 cache, L3 cache or the main virtual memory?  It was my understanding volatile is ignored on x86.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling, your understanding is wrong, and `volatile` has nothing to do with a particular architecture. C doesn't have a model for cache hierarchies or such things. `volatile` always forces a full load instruction for the architecture to be issued. If you have doubts about that, just try it with some short code that shows the difference and look into the assembler (e.g gcc option `-S`).

Comment: @JensGustedt: What is that "short code" that shows the difference?

Comment: @JensGustedt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207077/example-c-code-that-demonstrates-volatile-in-disassembly

Comment: @JensGustedt: I was wrong as you say.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, run some code :) I whipped up some similar (slightly less abominable) test code (win32 C++ app in msvs 2k10)

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    int a = 0;
    volatile int b = 0;

    a = 1; //breakpoint 1
    b = 2; //breakpoint 2
    *(int *) &b  = 0; //breakpoint 3
    *(volatile int *) &b  = 0; //breakpoint 4

    return 0;
}
```

When compiled for release, I am allowed to breakpoint at 2 and 4, but not 1 and 3.

My conclusion is that the typecast determines the behavior and 1 and 3 were optimized away. Intuition supports this - otherwise compiler would have to keep some type of list of all locations of memory listed as volatile and check on every access (hard, ugly), rather than just associating it with the type of the identifier (easier and more intuitive).

I also suspect it's compiler specific (and possibly flag specific even within a compiler) and would test on any platform before depending on this behavior.

Actually scratch that, I would simply try to not depend on this behavior :)

Also, I know you were asking specifically about arrays, but I doubt that makes a difference. You can easily whip up similar test code for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

like you said, its "undefined". Which means demons can come out of your nose. Please stick to the "defined" behaviours as much as possible. A `volatile` specifier will ask the compiler to *not* optimize the value, since its an "important" and critical value that might cause problems if changed due to different optmization mechanisms. But that's all it *can* do.