# Example C code that demonstrates volatile in disassembly?

Tags: c, volatile

What is a short illustrative C program that demonstrates the difference between volatile and non-volatile in the disassembly?

ie

```
int main()
{
    volatile int x;

    ???
}
```

vs

```
int main()
{
    int x;

    ???
}
```

What can we replace both `???` with such that the generated code is different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for example:

```
x = 0;
```

If `x` is not `volatile`, the compiler will see that it's unused and will probably eliminate it (either the `x = 0;` statement or even the variable itself) completely from the generated code as an optimization.

However, the `volatile` keyword is **exactly for preventing the compiler from doing this.** It basically tells the code generator "whatever you think this variable is/does, don't second guess me, I need it." So then the compiler will treat the volatile variable as accessed and it will emit the actual code corresponding to the expression.

Comment: I just tested it and you are correct.  The store `x = 0` is eliminated in the nonvolatile version in gcc -O2, whereas it is not with the volatile version.

Comment: "you are correct" - I'm always correct. (JK) :P You're welcome.

Comment: This is a "hasty generalization" fallacy from the specific to general. :)

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling But come on, it's permitted since we're scientists, right? :D

Comment: I agree with you provided you mean the exact opposite of what you just said - ie it's specifically not permitted precisely because we're scientists. :))

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling Feel the breeze of sarcasm in my comment. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the shortest example, but it's a common use of `volatile` in *embedded systems*, assuming `x` points to the address of a register, if `volatile` is not used, the compiler will assume the value of `x` doesn't change and will remove the loop:

```
volatile long *x = (long*) REGISTER_BASE;
while (!(x&0x01)) {
   //do nothing;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
x=1;
x=2;
return x;
```

Turn on optimization an check the disassembly for both.